# Accelerating fluid making an angle with horizontal

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, acceleration, fluid-statics, statics

The proofs of the two equations (1) and (2) below are given at the end of this question in the last image.

$$\frac{dP}{dy} = -ρg$$.......... (1)

Where P is pressure and ρ is density of fluid.

$$\frac{dP}{dx} = -ρa$$.......... (2)

Where $a$ is the acceleration in x direction.

The coordinate system has been chosen as in the image:
[image]

The edge is at the origin.

Now my question is:
There is a well known result that a fluid accelerating in horizontal direction, makes an θ with its free surface with horizontal, as in the image:
[image]

Then, $$tan~θ = \frac{a}{g}$$ (This result is for acceleration in x direction and and no components should exist in y direction)

Now to prove this, I divided equation (2) by (1) and we get,
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{a}{g}$$

Similar to $$tan~θ = \frac{a}{g}$$
The only difference is LHS are different. Of any mathematical curve $dy/dx$ gives the slope which is also $tan~θ$.

But here for which curve do we get that $tan~θ$ equals $dy/dx$?
It might be the free surface of the fluid, but how do we justify that?

The proofs of equation (1) and (2):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrating the equation, you get $$P=-\rho a x-\rho g y+C$$At the free surface, the pressure is zero:  $$-\rho a x-\rho g y+C=0$$and the free surface is a plane.  The slope of the free surface is dy/dx:  $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{a}{g}$$